# Android WorkManager and Worker

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have the following bit of code below. I need to be able to run the WorkerUtil.periodicSchedulerWorker every 15 minutes. What I noticed is that it only runs once and then never repeats afterward. And when it does run for the first time, all the chained Worker doesn't run. Any idea as to why it might not be running every 15 minutes? or what I can do to improve the current code. From the documentation, it looks like, after 15 min, it can decide to take longer to run, which is fine in my case. I want to make sure it's guaranteed to run in that time. I have double-checked all the constraints and BackofffCriteria, which all look fine.

I know there's PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder, but we can't chain repeated work with it.

```
fun WorkManager.addFamilyUpdate(): WorkContinuation =
    beginWith(WorkerUtil.refreshSomething)
        .then(WorkerUtil.retrieveSomething)
        .then(WorkerUtil.getSomethingElse)
        .then(WorkerUtil.profileImageDoaloader)
        .then(WorkerUtil.refreshWidgetUI)



 val periodicSchedulerWorker =  OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicFamilyWidgetsSchedulerWorker()
            .setInitialDelay(REFRESH_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()

fun WorkContinuation.addFollowUpUpdate(): WorkContinuation =
    then(WorkerUtil.periodicSchedulerWorker)

class PeriodicSchedulerWorker(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .addFamilyUpdate()
            .addFollowUpUpdate()
            .enqueue()

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the Swift tag on Android Kotlin code?

Comment: Does any worker in `addFamilyUpdate` throw an exception or failed? I tried with a similar setup to you and only failed to repeat when one of the tasks is failed

Comment: None of them fails in my setup. They all run successfully the first time. @TuanChau

Comment: Can you update with the code that starts the 1st run?

Answer (score 0):

```
val periodicSchedulerWorker =  OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicFamilyWidgetsSchedulerWorker()
           .setInitialDelay(REFRESH_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .build()
```

The problem was that the references for each of the val variables were not initialized. For the above *periodicSchedulerWorker*, I Just turned into a function and that fixed my problem. I was originally following the android documentation, not sure what changed:

```
fun periodicSchedulerWorker() =  OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicFamilyWidgetsSchedulerWorker()
           .setInitialDelay(REFRESH_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .build()
```